# int to float pointers

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, unsafe

In C++ there is a float value being put into an int:

```
int value = *(int *)(&myFloatValue);
```

This value gets passed to a program I am writing in C#. It is not known at run-time whether the value will be of type int or of float. I must account for both options. Obviously if it is an int, I already have it. However if it is a float I need to change it (not cast) it its float value. How do I do this? I tried  using pointers in C# but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: 1) How can you not know a type at runtime? 2) by "change" you mean re-interpret cast?

Comment: I don't really understand? How do you pass the value? Via a method call? Is there a prototype for that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the reverse in your C# code:

```
float myFloatValue = *(float *)(&value);
```

And that should work.

(Just make sure that value isn't inside of a managed type, it must be on its own)

EDIT: Make sure you declare the body of code you are doing this in as `unsafe`

Answer (score 8):

`BitConverter.GetBytes` and `BitConverter.ToFloat().`

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you're asking, I recommend unions?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct IntOrFloat
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int asInt32;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float asFloat;
}
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx):

```
// assuming 'bytes' is byte[4]
float value = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes);
//   or     = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(integer));
```

Another thing you could do, if you knew what type the value would be before you called that method, would be to utilize Operator Overloading on the P/Invoke side:

```
// [DllImport("x.dll")]
// public static extern void YourCall(ref float value);

// [DllImport("x.dll")]
// public static extern void YourCall(ref int value);

if (someCondition)
{
    float value = 0.0f;
    NativeMethods.YourCall(ref value);
    this.frob(value);
}
else
{
    int value = 0;
    NativeMethods.YourCall(ref value);
    this.frob(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BitConverter`, but it's really kind of ugly. Your C++ to C# interface is really messy - passing a value that can be either an int or a float in the same argument. I suggest you do one of the two:

1. Pass *both* an int and a float, and decide which is the right one in C#
2. Pass just one number, in a type that can hold all floats and all ints - `double`.